# How to scale the contentview to multiple screen sizes? SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

Newbie here! I am building a quiz app using Swiftui, I built the view controller by previewing it in an iPhone 11 simulator.

And I thought the controlview would fit other iPhone sizes, like iPhone 8. Because Swiftui has a built-in auto layout.

But when I run the iPhone 8 simulator some of the content in the control view is not visible because they are below the screen.

Is there a way to fix it?

I tried to play with multiple Spacer() and different paddings but I can't seem to make it look good on both screen at the same time.

This is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct questionOne: View {


    @State var totalClicked: Int = 0
    @State var showDetails = false
    @State var isSelected = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            TRpic().frame(width: 350.0, height: 233.0).cornerRadius(10).padding(.top, 80)

            Spacer()

            Text(verbatim: "What's the capital of Turkey?")
                .font(.title)
                .padding(.bottom, 60)
                .frame(height: 100.0)




            Button(action: {}) {

                Text("Istanbul")
            }.buttonStyle(MyButtonStyle())


            Spacer()

            Button(action: {self.isSelected.toggle()}) {
                Text("Ankara")
            }.buttonStyle(SelectedButtonStyle(isSelected: $isSelected))


            Spacer()

            Button(action: {}) {
                Text("Athens")

            } .buttonStyle(MyButtonStyle())

            Spacer()



            NavigationLink(destination: questionTwo()) {
        VStack {
                Text("Next Question")

               Adview().frame(width: 150, height: 60)
                }

               }

            }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
        }
    }

struct MyButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {

  func makeBody(configuration:

    Self.Configuration) -> some View {
    configuration.label
      .padding(20)
      .foregroundColor(.white)
      .background(configuration.isPressed ? Color.red : Color.gray)
      .cornerRadius(10.0)
  }
}

struct SelectedButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {

    @Binding var isSelected: Bool

    public func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .padding(20)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .background(isSelected ? Color.green : Color.gray)
            .cornerRadius(10.0)
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXren.jpg)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcWeV.png)

Answer (score 0):

Being in the given context I guess you do not want a scroll view, so regarding spacing I suggest using a `VStack` with spacing parameter `VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: n){ ... }` and remove the Spacers, if between 2 views you need another distance than n, just use `padding` to add some extra space.
This should adjust everything to fit the height of any screen, including the image, so do not need a fixed frame for it.

But, you might have a very wide image that could go beyond safe area, so, you could set a maximum width for the image as being the screen width

```
struct questionOne: View {

   var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometryProxy in
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20) {

                TRpic().frame(maxWidth: geometryProxy.size.width, alignment: .center)
                       .padding([.leading, .trailing], 10)
                  .......               
            }  
        }
   }
```

Comment: I guess it was the fixed frame. I deleted  " .frame(width: 350.0, height: 233.0)" and the whole view fits in both! Thank you! But the thing is I have 50 control views like this with 50 different pictures in it. I was using the fixed frame to have a standard look. Do you have a suggestion about how to do that?

Comment: And even if I had continue with the fixed frame. As you can see from the screenshot (I added a link just below the code in the question) there is plenty of space in the control view. I just feel like Spacer() doesn't work evenly.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and it looks way better than before. iPhone 11 screen look a little weird though, I posted a new screenshot below the code.

Comment: @IrfanKaya  A `Spacer()` before `NavigationLink` should solve the problem, it will force the `VStack` to use the entire screen

Comment: With Spacer() iPhone 11 screen looks okay but it messes up iPhone 8 view. Thanks for your patience and effort. I just don't think it's going to work this way. I have to change the whole thing. I think Apple wants people to use scroll view.

Comment: I checked it again today it totally works on both screens! I don't know how it's possible because I didn't update Xcode or anything. Thanks again!